# Best design of tables in database for dynamic dropdown jQuery

Tags: jquery, mysql, codeigniter

I have a case to create a page in my web using dropdown list that will be dynamic based on MySQL Table. I am using codeigniter PHP to develop it. I have a prototype of the tables like this :

```
TABLE PRINTER TONER
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ID PRINTER |  BRAND       |  TYPE              |  TONER  |    STOCK   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      1     |  HP Laserjet |   3030, 1020, 3055 | 12A     |            |
|            |              |    1200            | 15A     |            |
|            |              |    P1106           | 35A     |            |
|            |              |    PIXMAX          | 328     |            |
|            |              |    1160, 1320      | 49A     |            |
|            |              |    2015D           | 53A     |            |
|            |              |    P1102, PRO1102W | CE285A  |            |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

TABLE PRINTER INK
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ID PRINTER |  BRAND       |  TYPE      |  COLOR  |  BLACK | STOCK COLOR  | STOCK BLACK  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      2     |  HP DESKJET  |   F2410    | HP703   | HP60   |              |              |
|            |              |   810C     | HP49    | HP20   |              |              |
|            |              |   1220C    | HP78    | HP45   |              |              |
|            |              |   840C     | HP17    | HP15   |              |              |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Should I create ID_PRINTER one by one for one type ? I want to create some like this in my html :

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="selectError">Merk Printer :</label>
    <div class="controls">
       <select id="selectError" data-rel="chosen">
           <option>Brother Inject</option>
           <option>Canon</option>
           <option>Epson Dot Matrik</option>
           <option>Epson Deskjet Inject</option>
           <option>HP Laserjet</option>
           <option>HP Deskjet</option>
           <option>HP Office Jet</option>
           <option>Konica Minolta</option>
           <option>Panasonic</option>

          </select>
         </div>
</div>
```

The top of dropdown would be create hierarchy dropdown list based on database?

Answer (score 0):

You should do normalization on your database to reduce redundancy and size. Please read [this Wikipedia article for this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

For your case you have to do the following steps:
1. Split your Table `Printer Toner` into several tables like this:

**PrinterBrands**

```
---------------------
| id |  brandname   | 
---------------------
| 1  |  HP Laserjet | 
| 2  |  HP Colorjet |
...
```

**PrinterTypes**

```
------------------------------------
| id |  brand_id | type | toner_id |
------------------------------------
| 1  |     1     | 3030 |     1    |
| 2  |     1     | 1020 |     1    |

...
```

**TonerTypes**

```
----------------------------
| id |  toner_type | stock |
----------------------------
| 1  |     12A     |   23  |
| 2  |     15A     |   12  |
...
```

You can do this similar for the ink printers.
Now you can set the tables in relation to eachother and query them [see MySQL Select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html).
With this you can create a List of Printer, Brands or whatever.